# XCTest if Safari URL did open

Tags: swift, xctest

I need to test if an URL was successfully opened in Safari from my app. I am using `XCTest`.

The test would be like this:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.br")!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
//XCTAssert(<URL Did Open>)
```

Already tried finding the URL from `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")` but had no success.

How can I assert this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says you should use

```
func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], 
completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

And here you can check the boolean value, whether it was successful.